# Currency format for Indian(INR) and US(dollar) while exporting data using Apache POI doesn't work

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am exporting data using Apache POI and the data has both Indian and US currency to be displayed..but after applying separate DataFormats too I get the same format(Indian INR) applied to all data's.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        System.out.println("*******Export Excel*********");

        File myFile = new File("MyFirstExcel.xls");
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
        XSSFWorkbook xssfworkbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
        XSSFSheet sheet = xssfworkbook.createSheet("new sheet");

        XSSFCellStyle INRformatStyle = xssfworkbook.createCellStyle();
        XSSFCellStyle USformatStyle = xssfworkbook.createCellStyle();

        XSSFDataFormat df = xssfworkbook.createDataFormat();

        USformatStyle.setDataFormat(df.getFormat("[$$-409]#,##0.00;"));
        INRformatStyle.setDataFormat(df.getFormat("₹#,##0.00;"));

        sheet.setColumnWidth(0, 7000);

        XSSFRow row = sheet.createRow((short) 0);
        XSSFCell cell = row.createCell((short) 0);
        cell.setCellValue(100000.0);
        cell.setCellStyle(USformatStyle);

        XSSFRow row1 = sheet.createRow((short) 1);
        XSSFCell cell1 = row1.createCell((short) 0);
        cell1.setCellValue(100000.0);
        cell1.setCellStyle(INRformatStyle);

        xssfworkbook.write(out);
        out.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Expected $100,000.00
         ₹1,00,000.00

Actual   $1,00,000.00
         ₹1,00,000.00

Comment: I'd guess your `USformatStyle` uses the wrong format. For me both formats look pretty much the same, except for the sign of course

Comment: i tried various US DataFormats nothing worked...i feel Libreoffice is taking the default locale since i am in india.

Comment: You can try using DecimalFormat which is quite suitable for this case. For reference and examples check this out https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/decimalFormat.html

Comment: tried DecimalFormat..but i get a quote('₹1,40,000.00) before the data..also it shows a warning opening the file in MSexcel @robot_alien

Comment: Your code yields me `$100,000.00 ₹100,000.00` as result. Can't replicate your problem

Comment: ₹100,000.00 should be indian currency INR(₹1,00,000.00) formatted..you have replicated my problem.

Comment: @Naresh not enitrely, as your code yields `Actual $1,00,000.00 ₹1,00,000.00` as per your question. So we have 2 different wrong results

Comment: my output should be one Indian(INR) formatted and one US(dollar) formatted can you help me in getting that

Answer (score 1):

How the digit grouping is done in `Excel` is determined on the `Windows` system regional settings: [Change the Windows regional settings](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/change-the-windows-regional-settings-to-modify-the-appearance-of-some-data-types-edf41006-f6e2-4360-bc1b-30e9e8a54989). There is actually not a native option to set this via number format. So as long your system tells `Excel`: "We wants using format Hindi(India)" and so the digit grouping is set to `12,34,56,789` then this will be so for each number having thousands separator set.

Only possibility avoiding this is to set used system regional settings **not** to format `Hindi(India)` and so to set digit grouping **not** to `12,34,56,789`.

[image]

Or using kind of fake number format as `[$$-409]#\,###\,##0.00`.

```
...
USformatStyle.setDataFormat(df.getFormat("[$$-409]#\\,###\\,##0.00"));
...
```

This is not using comma as thousands separator but `,` as text within the digits flow. So system's digit grouping is bypassed.

Complete example:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

class CreateExcelDigitGroupings {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
  DataFormat dataformat = workbook.createDataFormat();
  CellStyle defaultCurrency = workbook.createCellStyle();
  defaultCurrency.setDataFormat((short)8); //see https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/BuiltinFormats.html
  CellStyle defaultUSDCurrency = workbook.createCellStyle();
  defaultUSDCurrency.setDataFormat(dataformat.getFormat("[$$-409]#,##0.00"));
  CellStyle fakeHindiCurrency = workbook.createCellStyle();
  fakeHindiCurrency.setDataFormat(dataformat.getFormat("₹#\\,##\\,##\\,##0.00"));
  CellStyle fakeUSDCurrency = workbook.createCellStyle();
  fakeUSDCurrency.setDataFormat(dataformat.getFormat("$#\\,###\\,##0.00"));

  Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Sheet1");

  double value = 12345678.9;
  Cell cell;
  int r = 0;
  sheet.createRow(r).createCell(0).setCellValue("defaultCurrency");
  cell = sheet.getRow(r++).createCell(1);
  cell.setCellValue(value);
  cell.setCellStyle(defaultCurrency);

  sheet.createRow(r).createCell(0).setCellValue("defaultUSDCurrency");
  cell = sheet.getRow(r++).createCell(1);
  cell.setCellValue(value);
  cell.setCellStyle(defaultUSDCurrency);

  sheet.createRow(r).createCell(0).setCellValue("fakeHindiCurrency");
  cell = sheet.getRow(r++).createCell(1);
  cell.setCellValue(value);
  cell.setCellStyle(fakeHindiCurrency);

  sheet.createRow(r).createCell(0).setCellValue("fakeUSDCurrency");
  cell = sheet.getRow(r++).createCell(1);
  cell.setCellValue(value);
  cell.setCellStyle(fakeUSDCurrency);

  sheet.autoSizeColumn(0);
  sheet.autoSizeColumn(1);

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("CreateExcelDigitGroupings.xlsx");
  workbook.write(out);
  workbook.close();
  out.close();

 }
}
```

Result in Excel having Format `Hindi(India)` set in `Windows regional settings` and so default digit grouping is set to `12,34,56,789`:

[image]

As you see for all default number formats the system's digit grouping is used. But my fake USD format works.

Result in OpenOffice 3.2.1 Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS.

[image]

Comment: The format  "[$$-409]#\,###\,##0.00"  throws Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are \b \t \n \f \r \" \' \\ ) error @Axel Richter

Comment: @Naresh: Yes. Of course in a `Java` string we needs escaping the backslash if backslash is meant as character. I have corrected that.

Comment: still i get the same  $1,00,000.00 ₹1,00,000.00

Comment: @Naresh: See my complete example. Do running that code and tell me what you see in your `Excel`. Or is it not `Excel` you are using? If not, what else?

Comment: defaultCurrency ₹1,23,45,678.90
defaultUSDCurrency $1,23,45,678.90
fakeHindiCurrency ₹1,23,45,678.90
fakeUSDCurrency $1,23,45,678.90        this is the output i get running your code..and i use LibreOffice calc

Comment: i tried opening the file in MS Excel and it shows defaultCurrency

$12,345,678.90
 

defaultUSDCurrency
 

$12,345,678.90
 

fakeHindiCurrency
 

₹1,23,45,678.90
 

fakeUSDCurrency
 

$12,345,678.90... my client uses both MSExcel and libreOffice

Comment: @Naresh: What LibreOffice version? I have tried yesterday using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS LibreOffice Calc version 5.4 and locale setting Hindi and this gave me defaultCurrency ₹ 1,23,45,678.90 defaultUSDCurrency $1,23,45,678.90 fakeHindiCurrency ₹1,23,45,678.90 fakeUSDCurrency $12,345,678.90 as expected.

Comment: libreOffice 14.04LTS and LibreOffice Version: 4.2.8.2

Comment: @Naresh: Found an old `OpenOffice.org 3.2.1` in my Ubuntu and even this works as expected. So sorry, cannot reproducing your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with the following modifications to the currency formats

```
  USformatStyle.setDataFormat(df.getFormat("$#,##0.00"));
  INRformatStyle.setDataFormat(df.getFormat("₹#,##0.00"));
```

Comment: both gives the same currency formatting(the comma seperation)..Expected $100,000.00 ₹1,00,000.00

Answer (score 0):

Finally found that Libreoffice Calc takes the regional language formatting(by default I get indian formatting)..works fine in MS excel.